# Is this the correct definition of a local trivialization?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

I have seen several people defining the notion of "local trivialization" differently. So I'd like to know if I understood the definition correctly. The following is what I think is the correct definition:

---

**Definition:** Let $(M,\tau _M)$ be a topological space. Suppose that $E$ is a set and $\pi :E\to M$ is surjective map. We say that $(U,\varphi )$ is a **local trivialization of $\pi$ with rank** $r$ if the following propositions are true:

1. $U\in \tau_M$
2. $\varphi :\pi ^{-1}[U]\to U\times \mathbb{R}^r$ is a homeomorphism with respect to the topology $\{\pi^{-1}[O]\cap \pi ^{-1}[U]:O\in\tau_M\}$ in $\pi ^{-1}[U] $ and the product topology of $\tau _M$ with the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^r$;
3. $\pi =\pi _1\circ \varphi $ in which $\pi _1:U\times \mathbb{R}^r\to U$ is given by $\pi _1(x,y):=x$;
4. For all $q\in U$ we have that $E_q:=\pi ^{-1}[\{q\}]$ is $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and $\varphi _q:E_q\to \mathbb{R}^r$ defined by $\varphi _q(x):=\pi _2\circ \varphi (x)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces in which $\pi _2:U\times \mathbb{R}^r\to \mathbb{R}^r$ is given by $\pi _2(x,y):=y$

---

**My question is:** Is the above definition correct? If it's wrong, could you please tell me the correct definition?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: This is correct (if you consider the real case. Otherwise, you should just take a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space). Note that in the smooth setting, one also require $\pi : E \rightarrow M$ to be a smooth map between smooth manifolds.

Comment: $\pi$ does not induce a quotient topology. It is the other way: If you have a surjection $f : A \to B$ from a space $A$ to a set $B$, then you can give $B$ the quotient topology.

Comment: @PaulFrost You’re right. So, what is the name of the topology $\{\pi^{-1}[O]:O\in\tau_M\}$ in $E$?

Comment: @rfloc that is called the initial topology. However, I don't think that is the topology one puts on, e.g, the tangent bundle, is it?

I have only seen the case where $E$ already is a topological space, then you consider $\pi^{-1}(U)$ with the subspace topology induced from $E$.
Where did you find this definition where $E$ only needs to be a set?

Comment: If you used that topology, then two different points of the same fibre wouldn't have separate neighbourhoods, so your $E$ wouldn't be Hausdorff. Is that what you want?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz There's no problem, because I'll assume that $(M,\tau _M)$ is a Hausdorff second-countable topological space.

Comment: The problem is that, if you take that topology, now every fibre will have the trivial topology, so you would need to consider the trivial topology on $\mathbb R^r$ as well.

Comment: Again, where did you find this definition where $E$ only needs to be a set? maybe you skipped some details.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Please see my newer question. That question may clarify why I thought that was unnecessary to assume that $E$ is a topological space.

Comment: @rfloc my objection remains. If you put the initial topology on $E$, then the fibres will have the trivial topology and it is unreasonable to ask them to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^r$ with the standard topology.

Answer (score 1):

The definition I know goes as follows:

Work in a fixed category: the category of topological spaces, the category of topological manifolds or the category of smooth manifolds.

**Definition**. If $B$ is a space, then a bundle over $B$ is a morphism $\pi:E\to B$.

**Definition**. Let $\pi:E\to B$, $\pi':E'\to B$ be two bundles over $B$. A pair of morphisms $f:E\to E'$ and $g:E'\to E$ is an isomorphism of the bundles $\pi$ and $\pi'$ if $\pi'f=\pi$, $\pi g=\pi'$, $fg=\mathrm{id}_{E'}$ and $gf=\mathrm{id}_{E}$.

**Definition**. Let $\pi:E\to B$ be a bundle and $A\subseteq B$ be a subspace. We define the bundle $\pi':E'\to A$, where $E'=\pi^{-1}[A]$ and $\pi'$ is the restriction of $\pi$. This bundle is called the restriction of $\pi:E\to B$ to $A$ and I will denote it by $\pi|A$ here.

If you want to define a locally trivial bundle, it may be easier to do it like this, instead of defining a local trivialisation.

**Definition**. Two bundles $\pi:E\to B$, $\pi':E'\to B$ over $B$ are locally isomorphic if there is an open cover $\mathcal U$ of $B$ such that $\pi|U$ is isomorphic to $\pi'|U$ for every open $U\in\mathcal U$.

**Definition**. The bundle $\pi:E\to B$ is called locally trivial with fibre $F$ if it is locally isomorphic to the trivial bundle $p_1:B\times F\to B$.

All of this is from chapter 2 of Husemoller's book *Fibre bundles* (Springer's Graduate texts in mathematics, 20).

However, if you really want to define what a local trivialisation is, then you could do it like this:

**Definition**. Given an open $U\subseteq B$, a local trivialisation on $U$ with fibre $F$ of the bundle $\pi:E\to B$ is an isomorphism of the restriction $\pi|U$ and the trivial bundle $p_1:U\times F\to U$.